# pip can't install in python-3.10.5. What I do now?

Tags: python, ssl, pip, python-3.10

```py
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (22.0.4)
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

1. I am use ubuntu-20.4
2. I update my python version -3.10.5

Comment: It seems like the command line can't connect to the server... Maybe your wifi isn't connected? Try downloading from the python website: https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: How did you update to python 3.10.5? Did you compile it by hand?

Comment: https://cloudbytes.dev/snippets/upgrade-python-to-latest-version-on-ubuntu-linux   by this website.

Comment: "however the ssl module in Python is not available." is possibly your problem.

Comment: From a glance, that website basically suggest to break your system packaging to install 3.10. It would have been a lot better to leave the system alone, and install something separately yourself, e.g. using pyenv.

Comment: @9769953 Not "possibly", that's definitely the problem. However, the python version distributed by deadsnakes **does** include working ssl support (I use it myself). So, whatever OP has done after installing python 3.10 not only broke their package manager but also their ssl support. I'd restore from backup, this seems FUBAR.